# pjax beforesend being called multiple times?

Tags: javascript

I am using pjax and wanted to use the beforesend call to display a message to the user if there have been unsaved changes to the form.  I am using the following javascript code

```
$(document).on('pjax:beforeSend', function() { 
    if (isDirty) {
        alreadyHandled = true;
        return confirm('You have unsaved changes! Are you sure you want to continue?');
        }
        return true;
    });
```

and it is returning multiple windows and I am not sure why.  Why is it displaying the same window multiple times and what can I do to make sure that it only throws it once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I was binding pjax multiple times to the same events.  Just going through the app and being a lot more careful with my jquery selectors has solved the problem.